# Embedding PHP snippet in HTML - syntax error

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a simple PHP/HTML page and I keep getting a syntax error on the final  tag.  I have no idea what the problem is.  Can anybody help me?  Here's my code:

```
<h2 class="date">
        <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT 'id', 'date', 'topic', 'event' FROM 'events'");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        ?>
            <h2><?php echo $row['topic'];?></h2> 
            <p><?php echo $row['event'];?></p>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </h2>
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I think you should use backticks (`) instead of single quotes (') for the SQL though.

Comment: your query should be   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `date`, `topic`, `event` FROM `events`");

Comment: @pang the only thing the error message says is "there is a syntax error on line 71"

Comment: @UditTrivedi i replaced my query with the one you posted and the error remains.  it sucks because the error message doesn't give any hint to want the problem is.

Comment: can you please give what is on line no 71

Comment: @pang i switched the single quotes to backticks, but the error message is still there.

Comment: @UditTrivedi line 71 is the final </h2> tag that closes <h2 class="date">

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what was wrong, I had a small error at the top of my page.  Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As far as syntax I do not see any errors. I usually do not use ' or at-least use back-ticks ` with mysql, that could be it but idk if MySQL supports them; can't hurt to check. Sometimes php will report an error in that general vicinity if there is a problem with your mysql_query... are you sure all of your variables loaded in properly? Try echoing some of the data you imported.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, date, topic, event FROM events");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<h2>".$row['topic']."</h2> 
            <p>".$row['event']."</p>";

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your final `</p>` be followed by closing inverted commas? And perhaps a semi-colon too?

Comment: still producing the same error message.  i'm not sure, but maybe it has something to do with the fact that i'm doing it in dreamweaver, and the program is just being anal about something silly.